# Codeigniter - Page redirect not working after submitting button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert and update data in my database using `ajax` to my controller. Now my data is inserting and updating precisely after I click the button. But my data on my view page is not updating. I need to refresh again the page to update my view and the success message to display

PS: It's firing sometimes, and sometimes not, Can't understand the behaviour

**Below is my JS file for ajax**

```
$('#triger').click(function(){
                    var btn_value = $('#triger').val();
                    var tenant_id = $('#tenant_id').val();
                    var calldisp_id = $('#calldisp_id').val();
                    var disposition_name = $('#disposition_name').val();
                    var disposition_code = $('#disposition_code').val();
                    var email = $.map($("#tags span"), function(elem, index){
                         return $(elem).text();
                    }); 
                    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(email);
                    //alert(myJsonString);
                        if(btn_value == 'Create'){

                            $.ajax({
                                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin/call_disposition/create_email_dispo_dre",
                                method:"POST",
                                data:{email:myJsonString,
                                      disposition_name:disposition_name,
                                      disposition_code:disposition_code,
                                      tenant_id:tenant_id},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success:function(data){

                                },
                            });
                        }
                        else if(btn_value == 'Update'){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin/call_disposition/update_email_dispo_dre",
                                method:"POST",
                                data:{email:myJsonString,
                                      disposition_name:disposition_name,
                                      disposition_code:disposition_code,
                                      calldisp_id:calldisp_id,  
                                      tenant_id:tenant_id},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success:function(data){


                                },
                          });
                        }

                });
```

**Below is my Controller**

```
public function create_email_dispo_dre($id){

    $this->_rules();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->update($id);
    } else {
    $data = array(
            'tenant_id' => $this->input->post('tenant_id',TRUE),
            'disposition_code' => $this->input->post('disposition_code',TRUE),
            'disposition_name' => $this->input->post('disposition_name',TRUE),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email',TRUE)           
            );
     $this->calldisp_model->insert($data);
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'admin_faqs_success');
     redirect('admin/call_disposition/update/'.$id);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax request for update:
In the success section:

```
success:function(data){
},
```

you need to call a page reload:

```
window.location.reload();
```

so your code becomes:

```
success:function(data){
    window.location.reload();
},
```

Comment: Are you saying that your page is not refreshing with the code?

Comment: it's refreshing because I'm using POST method. but I think the redirect is not working because after I refresh my page manually. the flashdata message will appear

Answer (score 0):

In controller

you have to add

`echo json_encode(array('success'=>'1'));` instead of `redirect('admin/call_disposition/update/'.$id);` because you used datatype "json";

and change success function an ajax request Like

```
success:function(data){
   if(data.success=='1'){
     window.location.reload();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter when you execute an Ajax call you can't redirect from the controller function. If you want to seemlessly update the page after clicking #trigger you have to echo the result in your controller

```
echo json_encode($html_you_want_to_display);
```

and then in your ajax success clause you need to update the div with the result from the echo by setting the innerHtml to the result. Hope this helps